# How to select a same data from database

Tags: mysql

My database table 'user' have below details

```
 ---------------------------------------
 id |  username  |   ref   |   email
 ---------------------------------------
 1  |  name1     |   0     |    email@email.com
 2  | name2      |   0     |   email@email.com
 3  |  name3     |  0      |  email@email.com
 4  | name4      |  3      |    email@email.com
 5  | name5      | 3       |   email@email.com
 6  |  name5     |  3      |  email@email.com
 ---------------------------------------
```

this means id 3 is the referrer of 4,5,6
My question is  how to select name of id 4,5 & 6 using id 3

Comment: `SELECT username FROM user WHERE ref = 3`?

Comment: Two users have the same username, and all share the same email address. This is going to get pretty confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self join

```
select u1.*, u2.username as ref_name
from user u1
left join user u2 on u1.ref = u2.id
```

Comment: this condition `u1.ref = u2.id` will never match

Comment: @Rahul why not?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use a normal `WHERE` clause like

```
select username from tbl where ref=3;
```

If you need a listed username then consider using `group_concat()` and `group by` ref column

```
select group_concat(username)
from tbl1
group by ref;
```

To me looks like you wanted something like below which is same as saying `where ref = 3`

```
select id, username
from tbl1
where id in (select distinct id from tbl1 where ref = 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user u1 
left join user u2 on u2.ref = u1.id
where u1.id = 3
```